# Import records - Partner Community

Tags: leads, partner-communities, data-import-wizard

Is it possible to import records (e.g. Leads) in Partner Communities? I have given the "Import Leads" permission to my partner user but i don't see the "Import Leads" button like in internal Salesforce users. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and opened a Salesforce case. According with the Salesforce support team, this feature isn't available for "Partner central" community template. Its only available for "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce" template. The workaround for the Partner central would be via customization.

Comment: Hi Gustavo. This is correct, i also opened a Case and the answer was the same.